# Contact being ended when it still exist

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on a tilemap game that can best be described by making reference too the image below.
The red tile is my floor which collides with  my player and it also handles whether or not the sprite can jump (if no contact do NOT jump). So while walking across the red tile I "CAN JUMP"
however if I run into the yellow tile. my NSLog again prints "can jump" since I have a long on the contact of the player and wall. BUT if i move away from the yellow tile WHILE still walking on the red. I get a notification saying "Cannot jump" and as a result my sprite can no longer jumps since it does not detect a collision between my player and my floor.

Would love if i could be given ideas on how to handle this. 
thanks

```
floor.name = @"floor";
floor.position = CGPointMake(x + w/2, y + h/2);
floor.zPosition=0;

floor.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(w, h)];
floor.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;
floor.physicsBody.categoryBitMask =  floorCategory;
floor.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=spriteCategory;
floor.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;




- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (floorCategory|spriteCategory)) {

      NSLog(@"Can jummp");
      onFloor=YES;

 }
}
- (void) didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t contactTest = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (contactTest == (spriteCategory| floorCategory)) {


    NSLog(@"dont jumps");
    onFloor = NO;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance get a lot of can / cannot jump messages very quickly?

Comment: @sangony no i dont, when i jump i get "Cant jump" and when i land on the platform i get "Can jump".

Comment: So your guy shows "no jump" if he makes contact with yellow AND red and then loses contact with yellow while still having contact with red?

Comment: @sangony no, sorry if i explained it wrong . when i LAND on red from wherever it says" Can jump" if i touch yellow WHILE still standing on red it says"CAN jump" but if i walk right and break contact with YELLOW BUT still on RED. it says "NO jump".

Comment: What category is the yellow object?

Comment: @sangony They are both the same floor category. I just used the different colors so I could explain the situation. However they are the booth the same property from tiled.

Comment: Your revised floor code has PCWallCategory... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54214/discussion-between-jennifer-and-sangony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved in chat.

The problem was that both the red and yellow object had the same physics category (floorCategory).

The player made contact with the yellow object while already having contact with the red object. The player then lost contact with the yellow object, by moving right, and triggered the didEndContact: method due to the yellow object having the same category as the red object and thereby setting the "No Jump" state.

The solution is to add a "wall category" the side of the yellow object and thereby preventing didEndContact: to fire.